# Textbox wont update

Tags: winforms, user-interface, textbox

So i'm making a basic yahtzee program i c#, and im trying to make an actual gui and not just use the console. However i have a problem with the textbox. When i roll the dice, i want the textbox to display the number rolled. Now it shows nothing. I use two classes, one for the actual program and one for handling the gui. This is the yahtzee class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Yahtzee
{
    class YahtzeeScorer {
        Random rndm = new Random();
        Form1 gui = new Form1();
        String dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4, dice5;

       public void rollDice()
        {
            String a = Console.ReadLine();
            this.dice1 = rndm.Next(1, 7).ToString();
            this.gui.tbDice_SetText(this.dice1);
        }

        static void Main(String[] args) {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            YahtzeeScorer ys = new YahtzeeScorer();
            Application.Run(ys.gui);
            ys.rollDice();
            Console.WriteLine("The result was: " + ys.dice1 );
            Console.Read();
        }

    }
}
```

And this is the gui class form1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Yahtzee
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void tbDice_SetText(String s)
        {
            //this.ActiveControl = tbDice;
            Console.WriteLine("SetText");
            tbDice.Text = s;
        }

        public void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }



    }
}
```

tbDice is the name of the textbox component. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examine the lines:

```
Application.Run(ys.gui);
ys.rollDice();
```

`rollDice()` will not be called until the application exits, because the thread running `Main()` will block on `Application.Run()` until it does.

Instead, try calling `ys.rollDice()` in something like a button event handler.

**UPDATE**

You are mixing your game logic and your presentation logic by putting both aspects in YahtzeeScorer.  I would suggest that you move the game logic into a separate class like this:

```
public class YahtzeeGame
{
     public string rollDice()
     {
        return rndm.Next(1, 7).ToString();
     }    
}


public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    YahtzeeGame game = new YahtzeeGame();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // You need to create a new Button on your form called btnRoll and 
    // add this as its click handler:
    public void btnRoll_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tbDice.Text = game.rollDice();
    }
}
```

Comment: So i guess i can't make an instance of YahtzeeScorer in form1, can I call the buttonpress action from the yahtzeescorer? Can i decide in YS what the buttonpress in form1 should do? Would appreciate an example